# How to replace last digit of a version number with the preceding number using sed command for .json file

Tags: sed

I have a package.json file which has the version line number in it:

```
"version": "3.2.47",
```

I want to change the version number with sed so that the last part of the version number is 1 less. So in the case of the example above it would become:

```
"version": "3.2.46",
```

Other example:

```
"version": "3.2.50",
```

would become:

```
"version": "3.2.49",
```

How would I do this? I tried just replacing the whole thing with anything at first and fell at this first hurdle because of the quotes.

Bear in mind that there will be other version numbers for other things in the same file, so it needs to target this particular line, the one with `"version":`  in it.

My attempt did nothing:

```
sed -i -E "s/\"version\": \"\d+\.\d+\.\d*\d\"/zzzz/g" package.json
```

Comment: I think it would be easier with Perl if that's an option? Or even `awk`?

Comment: don't know those, how would I do it with either of those?

Comment: What if the original line is: `"version": "3.2.00",` ?

Comment: patch number can be received with `sed -E "s/\"version\":[[:space:]]*\"[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/"`, but anyway it needs some arithmetic to be done outside

Comment: it will never be 00 so not a problem

Comment: `sed` is nothing Linux-specific, removed the according tag.

Comment: Graham in response to @anubhava asking what if the version number ended in `00` you said "it will never be 00 so not a problem" - so if it ends in `01` and we need to subtract `1` from it, what number should it end up as? Presumably not `00` since you've told us that the version can never be `00`.....

Comment: the original will never be 00, the replaced version can be.

Comment: and then you you can guarantee you'll never need to run this tool on it again in future? It might be better if you had a requirement like "if it's 0 leave it alone".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is json, you can process with a json-aware tool like `jq`. Naïvely:

```
jq '
    .version |= (
        split(".") as $a |
        ($a|last|tonumber-1) as $n |
        $a[0:-1]+[$n]|join(".")
    )
' package.json >package.json.new
```

Comment: Or with regex: `jq '.version |= sub( "(?<n>[0-9]+)$" ; "\(.n|tonumber-1)" )'`

Comment: you could check input by replacing `tonumber-1` with something like: `tonumber | if .>0 then .-1 else "bad number: \(.)\n"|halt_error(1) endif`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/"version":/!b;s/"/\\"/g;s/[0-9]+/$((&-1))/3;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Turn on extended regexp by setting the `-E` command line option.

If a line does not contain `"version":` perform no further processing.

Otherwise, quote double quotes, replace the third set of numbers by an arithmetic shell command and evaluate the result by way of echo.

N.B. Double quotes within the line being evaluated must be quoted so as not to interfere with the shell.

An alternate but messier solution:

```
sed -E 's/("version": ".*\..*\.)(.*)(",)/echo '\''\1'\''$((\2-1))'\''\3'\''/e' file
```

Comment: it's a bit shorter with perl: `perl -pe 's/"version"\s*:\s*"[^"]*\.\K\d+/$&-1/e'`

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s`:

```
$ gawk 'match($0,/^(\s*"version":.*\.)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a) { $0=a[1] a[2]-1 a[3]} 1' file
"version": "3.2.46",
```